# Could not establish trust relationship for SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: .net, web-services, ssl, soap, x509certificate2

I'm working on a project which service certificate does not include the "CN" attribute (so I can't create a DNS identity, but I can create a X509CertificateIdentity using the cert's thumbprint), to establish the secure channel.

The problem is that I'getting the error "Could not establish trust relationship for SSL/TLS secure channel".

On another projects, this worked for me

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
```

But not this time.

The certificates for both service and client are ok

Any help/hint would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.
Regards.

Comment: "does not include the "CN" attribute"
maybe, it includes Subject Alternative Names extension? And any code sample would give us more insight.

Comment: Yes, I it has the other parameters. For creating an identity, I use X509CertificateIdentity. The problem is that I get an error I can't avoid bypassing the SSL validation.

Comment: can you provide us your certificate? With the information you provided, we can only guess. Guessing is not the best way to figure out what is wrong. And code sample would give us more information.